# Boolean expression simplification

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, circuit

I am trying to simplify a Boolean expression with exactly 39 inputs, and about 500 million - 800million terms (as in that many and/not/or statements).

A perfect simplification is not needed, but a good one would be nice.

I am aware of the  [K-maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) , [Quine–McCluskey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer) algorithms. However I am also aware that these mechanisms would take way too long to simplify a circuit of this size based on what I have read

I would need to simplify this expression as much as possible within a 24 hour period.

After google searching, I find it difficult to find any resources for attempting to simplify a machine of quite this magnitude! Any resources out there or a library out there that can attempt to at least simplify this to some extent within a 24 time period?

Comment: What do you mean by "terms"? AND conjunctions? How many of the 39 variables are present in a term on average? What reduction would be regarded "good"? It would help to see a small sample of typical terms.

Comment: Out of curiosity, using your specific definition of _term_, how many unique terms are possible for 39 inputs? It sounds like there might be lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A greedy heuristic *Simplify* is described in the somewhat dated book

> Robert K. Brayton , Gary D. Hachtel , C. McMullen , Alberto Sangiovanni-Vincentelli
>   Logic Minimization Algorithms for VLSI Synthesis

You can find the chapter [online](https://books.google.de/books?id=VT2kzZBPvz4C&pg=PA49&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

*Simplify* is based on the *unate paradigm*. In divide-and-conquer style, it recursively applies *Shannon's* [expansion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_expansion_theorem) to split the function into smaller sub-functions. The heuristic rule is to split by the most binate variable first, i.e. the variable which separates the largest number of terms.

---

A second approach could be to use graph partitioning tools like [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) to split the terms into independent (or at least loosely related) subsets. But I am not aware that this has been tried sucessfully for logic synthesis tasks. My favorite search engine is sceptical and does not return any hits.

---

A more recent algorithm based on [Binary Decision Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) was [published](http://www.ocoudert.com/papers/pdf/soda95.pdf) in

> Olivier Coudert: Doing Two-Level Logic Minimization 100 Times Faster

The paper lists examples with very high number of terms similar to your task at hand.

A somewhat related simplification technique *BDD Sweeping* as described in [A Study of Sweeping Algorithms in the Context of Model Checking](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-832/paper_7.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535990/1531728 for resources about logic optimization, or simplication of boolean expressions.